# How to remove value a from a list in C , search by element?

Tags: c, list

Im trying to remove a value in my List in C. But its stop working, its is called. Thats is my function to remove:

```
int Excluir_Cadastro_paciente (C_paciente **inicio_cadastro_paciente,char cpf[12])
{
  C_paciente *aux,*per;
  if (*inicio_cadastro_paciente == NULL)
  {
    printf("\nEmpty List\n");
    return 1;
  } else {
    int achou = 0;
    per = *inicio_cadastro_paciente;
    aux = *inicio_cadastro_paciente;
    while(per != NULL) {
      if(strcmp(per->CPF , cpf) == 0 ){ //Achou
        aux = per;
        per = per->prox;
        aux->prox = per->prox;
        free(per);
        achou = 1;
        printf("Removed!");
        break;
        return 0;
      } else {
        per = per->prox;
      }
    }
    if(achou != 1){
      printf("Impossible to remove");
    }
    return 0;
  }
}
```

My struct:

```
struct cadastro_Paciente {
 char CPF[12]; 
 struct cadastro_Paciente *prox; 
};
typedef struct cadastro_Paciente C_paciente;
```

So the user types a var called cpf, then the function search for it and removes it.

Comment: Could you please format your code ?

Comment: Yes. is it better now?

Comment: as much as i appreciate it, not really...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you get a bit confused about your pointers `aux` and `per`. Also, although you pass the head as double pointer, you don't reflect any possible changes to the head, because you only use that pointer to get your initial values to your pointers.

You don't need the pointers. Just use the double pointer as iterator. I contains the address of the head at the beginning and the addresses of the `prox` members as you iterate.

When you find the node you want to delete, you skip the node by updating the list through that pointer.

Here's an updated version of your function. (I haven't tested this code. I've also taken the liberty to rename `inicio_cadastro_paciente` to `pac`. Much shorter, plus after the first iteration it's no longer the *inicio*.)

```
int Excluir_Cadastro_paciente(C_paciente **pac, const char *cpf)
{
    if (*pac == NULL) {
        printf("Empty List\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while ((*pac) != NULL) {
        if (strcmp((*pac)->CPF, cpf) == 0) {
            C_paciente *del = (*pac);

            *pac = (*pac)->prox;
            free(del);

            printf("Removed!\n");
            return 0;
        }

        pac = &(*pac)->prox;
    }

    printf("Nothing removed!\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you remove the wrong item, not one you found in `strcmp(per->CPF , cpf) == 0`, but the next one:

...

```
     per = per->prox;
```

...

```
     free(per);
```